# Sequel drops connections with SSL error when forked, why?

Tags: ruby, postgresql, nginx, database-connection, sequel

I've been checking out [Hanami](http://hanamirb.org/guides/) and discovered that my Sequel connections were dying with the following error:

`Sequel::DatabaseDisconnectError: PG::ConnectionBad: PQconsumeInput() SSL error: decryption failed or bad record mac: SELECT NULL`

No matter the server (thin, puma, webrick) or environment. After some experimentation, it turned out that the culprit was `gem 'shotgun'` in the `Gemfile` (hanami does not reload code). From the shotgun docs:

> Each time a request is received, it forks, loads the application in
>   the child process, processes the request, and exits the child process.

**When used in production with nginx, forked Sequel drops connections for the same reason.**

This can be ameliorated with the following code, but it will mean that one has to reconnect on every request:

```
SequelDB.extension :connection_validator
SequelDB.pool.connection_validation_timeout = -1
```

So it seems that Sequel's connection pool after forking is corrupted.

Why is Sequel doing this?

Answer (score 1):

When a process forks, each copy of the process shares the file descriptor used to talk to postgres. This isn't sequel specific or even Postgres specific although some libraries detect forking and do the reconnecting to the db for you (see this [discussion](https://github.com/jeremyevans/sequel/issues/691) on the sequel issue tracker - short version is that it's not going to happen with sequel)